# C# Net core 2.0 Console.ReadLine() in Linux, bash

Tags: c#, linux, bash, .net-core

Can you please tell me how to fix this problem: I run the console application through the terminal (sudo dotnet run --configuration Release) and in it i need to enter text from the keyboard (Console.ReadLine()), but when typing, I get...
��вавф����������������������������������������������������������������

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

        string test = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Also I tried to run the application in screen. The encoding is used - Unicode.

P.S I need some input and output support for Latin and Cyrillic

Comment: Please do not add pure text messages as picture. Include it into your question as text instead. Please also show the relevant code parts by providing a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Gerhardh ok, fixed

Comment: The other messages from your picture were not related to your question? Please add the source code you use.

Comment: @Gerhardh ok :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Linux distributions use UTF-8 encoding by default. While UTF-8 is **a** Unicode encoding, it is not the one meant by `Encoding.Unicode` - that means UTF-16.

Try `Encoding.UTF8`.